# Compression In a current carrying spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, spring

A spring with $N$ turns radius $R$ and spring constant $k$ with initial length $L$. Current $I$ is flown through it. Find the amount of compression in the spring.

I first tried this question using conserving energy and taking spring as an inductor. Initial magnetic energy $=$ final magnetic energy + spring potential energy.
But that didn't workout. Later I derived force on lateral surface of spring by using magnetic pressure but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure that you weren't given the length of the spring as well as the other data?

Comment: @PhilipWood yes the initial length is given to be L. Edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas that you might find useful...

(a) Assume that the spring behaves as a long solenoid. The magnetic flux through the central region of the solenoid will therefore be $\Phi _0 = \pi R^2 \mu_0 \nu I$ in which $\nu=\frac NL$.

(b) The flux leaving the geometrical end of the solenoid (and entering the other end) will be $\tfrac12\Phi_0$ (because at the end of a long solenoid, half the solenoid is missing!)

(c) But $\text{div} \vec B = 0$ so the flux, $\Phi-\tfrac12\Phi_0=\tfrac12\Phi_0$, that doesn't leave through the geometrical end must leave through the sides of the solenoid in the region near the end (and must enter through the sides at the other end). It is the radial component of this flux that exerts an axial motor effect (Laplace) force on the end turns of the solenoid, squashing it.

(d) The axial component of the motor effect force on a length d$z$ of the end region of solenoid, containing $\nu dz$ turns is
$$dF=B \sin \theta\ I\ 2 \pi R \nu dz$$
(e) But $B \sin \theta\ 2 \pi R dz$ is the flux, $d \Phi$, leaving the sides of the solenoid over the length $dz$ of solenoid.

(f) So the (axial) force on length $dz$ of solenoid is
$$dF=I \nu d \Phi$$

(g) Integrating, the total force on each end region is
$$F=I \nu \tfrac12 \Phi_0= \frac{\pi}{2} \mu_0 R^2 \frac{N^2}{L^2} I^2.$$

(h) The spring as a whole is therefore under this compressive force (negative tension), just as if I were pushing each end inward with my hands. We have already assumed that the spring is long compared with its diameter, so the end regions, where the field splays out and the compressive forces arise, are short compared with the total length of the spring. It is therefore a reasonable approximation to neglect the fact that the end regions *themselves* are not compressed as much as the rest of the spring.

(h) The last step should be pretty straightforward!

Comment: But doesn't the force act radially outward on the spring's coil idl×B.How does it squash it?

Comment: @ user735447 Please read (c) again, especially the second sentence. I've slightly modified (c) and (d) to help make this clearer.

Comment: @ user735447 Have you drawn a diagram of an end-region of the solenoid, showing the flux sprouting out ? This should help you think about it.

Comment: yes I got it. Thanks

Comment: This approach is both thoughtful and rigorous, but I'm thinking that the magnetic field produces by the open coils of a spring would be noticeably different from that produced by the tightly wound coils  of a solenoid.

Comment: Thinking in terms of the force between two parallel current carrying wires, the loops near the center of the spring would be attracted to loops both above and below, thus giving no net force. It is reasonable to assume that the shrinkage would occur only near the ends.

Comment: @R.W.Bird Interesting! (a) Open turns and tight turns; yes there would be a difference in the fields, though my feeling is that  the tight-turn textbook solenoid field would be a 'smoothed out' approximation to the field of the open turn spring (b) My argument is that all the end-region turns at one end of the spring experience a force towards the centre of the solenoid, and so do all those at the other end, so the *whole* spring is squashed, just as if I pushed in on each end with my hands. No *need* for middle turns to experience magnetic forces from neighbours.

Comment: Would the down-voter please explain the down-vote. Is the Physics wrong? Does the answer fail to address the question? Is the quality of explanation poor? We might all learn something.